# Netbeans editor won't expand window to whole screen?

Tags: netbeans

I'm using NB7.0, it used to be working fine, when I open a Java file, I can double click on the file name and expand the file to full screen, then double click the file name again to shrink it so I can see output panel and on the left there will be the project panel, now I don't know what I did, it don't expand to full screen any more, I can still "Undock Window", but it doesn't respond to "Maximize Window", how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out : "Reset Windows" will make it work like before.

Comment: I had the same problem with NetBeans 8.2

Comment: @MarkMcLaren Me too, and this answer helped.